# JS to monitor data usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, web-widget

I'm building a simple html5 app to monitor the total network traffic that's incoming and outgoing. Is it possible to know your bandwidth usage using js?

Comment: I don't know whether it's relevant to your needs, but the webtiming API coming in the next gen of browsers may be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/28/measuring-web-page-performance.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for the whole system -- at least not without some sort of client-side addon installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of the code in Firebug to do this. Firebug has a "Net" tab that monitors downloads and uploads.

Comment: This isn’t going to work unless the code is running inside a Firefox extension. Even then, it’ll be necessary to write some C++ code since there’s no API in Firefox for determining overall system resource usage.